# Fill in different Input Field in Table by Clicking Links with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, autofill

How do I get the value clicked in each row (generated using AddRowTable plugin), i.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".addRow-Max4").btnAddRow({maxRow:4, inputBoxAutoNumber:true});
$(".delRow").btnDelRow();
});
</script>
```

generates maximal 4 rows in a table and numbers each input box, so I get textfield1, textfield2 and so onin my table.

```
<table border="0" >
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Input your data</th>
    <th><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="addRow-Max4"/></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Apple</a> 
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Banana</a> 
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Mango</a>
    </td><td><input type="text" name="textfield" class="autofill" size="25"/></td>
    <td><img src="./images/cross.gif" class="delRow" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I might decide for Apple in row1, Mango in row2 and so on and would like that the according textfield for this row is filled.

I have

```
$("a[class=autofill]").live("click", function(){
$("input[name=textfield1]").val($(this).text());
return false;
});
```

but how do I have to adjust it to make it dynamic for each row. Let's say textfield1, textfield2, textfield3 and so on. As it is right now, I change the textfield1 each time a link is clicked. But I want to just change it if one of the corresponding (same row) link is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not get much of the insight for this issue. But here is my try to find all the input fields inside their parent TR.

```
$("a[class=autofill]").live("click", function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("input").val($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

This is what i tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/KU6Xw/

Comment: As i mentioned i did not get the exact insight but here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/KU6Xw/

Comment: Thank you! got what I wanted to do!